# Mongoose findById returning null

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to adjust information about a model. I am doing this by using model.find({_id: "id", function(err, foundModel){}); function. I also tried with findById and findByIdAndUpdate, but all dont seem to work.

The problem is that the find-function does not return any result, neither does it give an error.

Here is the model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//CREATE THE SCHEMA
var riderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    price: Number,
    points: {type: Number, default: 0},
    nationality: String,
    team: String,
    photo: String,
});

//CREATE THE MODEL
var Rider = mongoose.model("Rider", riderSchema);

//EXPORT THE MODEL
module.exports = Rider;
```

And here is the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/user");
var Race = require("../models/race");
var Result = require("../models/result");
var Rider = require("../models/rider");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var pointsArray = [
    250, 200, 175, 150, 130, 115, 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5
    ];

router.get("/:id/finalize", function(req, res){
        Result.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundResult){
            if(err){
                console.log("Something went wrong with finding the result to finalize");
            } else {
                console.log("This is the result I found: " + foundResult);
                var riders = [];
                riders = foundResult.riders;
                console.log(riders);

                var j = 0;

                riders.forEach(function(rider){
                    Rider.find({_id: rider}, function(err, foundRider){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("program tried to look up rider for the forEach loop finalizing the results, but could not find");
                        } else {
                            console.log(rider);
                            j = j + 1;
                            console.log("This is the " + j + "th rider I found: " + foundRider);
                            foundRider.points = foundRider.points + pointsArray[j];
                            console.log("done");
                        }
                    });
                });
                res.redirect("/results/admin");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the output I get after tweaking around a bit:

```
    This is the result I found: { _id: 5a2d259ab753ad08fc47881d,
  processed: 'results are filled in!',
  raceName: ' Tirreno-Adriatico (SR)',
  raceType: ' Stage Race',
  __v: 1,
  dateProcessed: 2017-12-10T12:17:35.243Z,
  riders: 
   [ 5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478813,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478814,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478817,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478816,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812,
     5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815 ],
  dateCreated: 2017-12-10T12:08:43.442Z }
["5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478813","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478814","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478817","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478816","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812","5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815"]
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a
This is the 1th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812
This is the 2th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478816
This is the 3th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d
This is the 4th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478812
This is the 5th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b
This is the 6th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f
This is the 7th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478813
This is the 8th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880a
This is the 9th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c
This is the 10th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811
This is the 11th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478817
This is the 12th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880c
This is the 13th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880d
This is the 14th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810
This is the 15th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478814
This is the 16th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880b
This is the 17th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809
This is the 18th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e
This is the 19th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815
This is the 20th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478809
This is the 21th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880e
This is the 22th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc47880f
This is the 23th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478811
This is the 24th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478810
This is the 25th rider I found: 
done
5a2d23cbb753ad08fc478815
This is the 26th rider I found: 
done
```

I am console logging a lot just to prove to myself that the ID's are there and how the objects/arrays are nested.

The problem is that the `Rider.find({_id: rider}, function(err, foundRider){` returns `null`.

Anyone can help me with this? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Best,

Rutger

Comment: How are you inporting your model file? as i cant see `Rider` defined anywhere in your router file(only in model)?

Comment: Hey Wrangler, Tnx for your reply. I added the header to the post. I did not include it in the post, but it was already there, so unfortunately not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OMG. I finally found out why nothing is working. I am seeding every time I start my server. All my riders are constantly removed and recreated with completely new ID's. So the old ones, that are stored in the results, never work.

lol.